# Accessibility: modal forms with ajax

Tags: html, accessibility, wcag

If I want to use modal forms with Ajax post-backs on a website and at the same time make it accessible to users without JavaScript I see 2 solutions:

1. Build the site with traditional forms and on the client side, with JavaScript, change the forms to modal forms and with ajax-post-backs. How this would be solved is not important. There are different ways to solve it. However it's more time consuming to implement and manage.
2. Build the site with modal Ajax forms and have some kind of message on the site saying that what the user should do if they don't have JavaScript. Call or whatever.

**My question is: Is solution #2 WCAG valid?**
And I would appreciate a reference to https://www.w3.org/WAI/standards-guidelines/wcag/ where this is mentioned.

I have searched a lot for an answer to this, https://www.w3.org/WAI/standards-guidelines/wcag/. But actually I have a hard time to understand these kind of documents.

This issue concerns a website for the public sector (hospital) in Sweden. The guidelines says:

- Follow WCAG 2.1 AA
- Consider WCAG 2.1 AAA

This is the same for all countries in EU (european union) concerning the public sector.

The guidelines I need too follow: https://webbriktlinjer.se/riktlinjer/1-utga-fran-wcag-2-1-niva-aa/ (only in Swedish)

- https://webbriktlinjer.se/ provide official guidelines for working
  with websites for the public sector.
- https://www.funka.com/en/ responsible for translation of WCAG on
  behalf of W3C and they refer to https://webbriktlinjer.se/ for
  guidelines.

The guidelines from https://webbriktlinjer.se/ says:
Follow the principle of progressive enhancement - first build everything with HTML then add CSS and JavaScript to enhance, https://www.gov.uk/service-manual/technology/using-progressive-enhancement/

Comment: https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/122106/74823 this is a very interesting discussion of the underlying question, if you need to support non-JS browsers at all.

Comment: Providing a non-js solution is largely not an accessibility question these days, see [the WebAIM survey](https://webaim.org/blog/survey7results/). Perhaps you could provide the user story you are aiming for?

Comment: @Andy and steveax
Thank you for your comments. I have edited my question and added more information. The issue is not if I should provide it or not. I have guidelines (law) to follow and as I understand it I can decide howto (within certain frames). So the question is still: If I decide to not support non-js visitors how should I solve it?

Is solution 2 sufficient? Or do I need to remove the modal-ajax-forms to? Meaning remove will require me to not showing them at the beginning. If not showing them it starts getting more complex/timeconsuming to solve.